# Unzip File on Shared Drive with Script

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I would like to extract files out of a zip file on a network shared drive.  However, the sub is throwing an exception--`VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objTarget'`

I am calling the sub like so:

`Extract "\\driveName\Folder\Path\Here" & file, "\\driveName\Folder\Path\Here\Unzipped"`

It's strange because the code to set `objSource` works correctly, but when the code attempts to set `objTarget`, it errors out.  Also, it works correctly when I specify a local drive.  I assume I have to do some modification to get it functioning correctly (if possible).  Below is the sub:

```
Sub Extract(ByVal myZipFile, ByVal myTargetDir)

    Dim intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget

    ' Create the required Shell objects
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    ' Create a reference to the files and folders in the ZIP file
    Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(myZipFile).Items()

    ' Create a reference to the target folder
    Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(myTargetDir)

    intOptions = 4

    ' Unzip the files
    objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions

    ' Release the objects
    Set objSource = Nothing
    Set objTarget = Nothing
    Set objShell  = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the network path. So your command would be:

```
Extract "\\driveName\Folder\Path\Here\" & file, """\\driveName\Folder\Path\Here\Unzipped"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Other possible reason for that error:

```
If objTarget Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "Target path not exist"
Else
    objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can manually open your file and remove the zip header.  Apparently, the zip header is a few characters and a null-terminated string, and if these are removed, the file unzips.  http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1302498 has more information, about halfway down the thread.